# Oreo (api 26) not able to receive broadcast from other module

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I have a module which will be used for downloading, once the file is downloaded I used to send an implicit brodcast.
In my app module I have the broadcast receiver to make some change settings once the download is completed.
In android 8 I'm not able to receive this broadcast, checking on documentation, the said to use explicit intent new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
But my problem is that my MyBroadcastReceiver.class is in my app module and not in my downloading module, so I cannot do something like this.

What are the other possibilities? I'm stuck with this new broadcast implementation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you truly mean "module" — and that all of this code is in a single app and a single process — please stop using system broadcasts. Use an in-process solution:

- `LocalBroadcastManager`, as Balu suggested
- greenrobot's EventBus
- `LiveData`
- RxJava
- etc.

Using system broadcasts has privacy, security, and performance implications.

But, let's pretend that by "module" you mean "app", or the code will be in separate processes, and so an in-process solution will not work.

> But my problem is that my MyBroadcastReceiver.class is in my app module and not in my downloading module, so I cannot do something like this.

If the receiver is registered in the manifest, you certainly can, by using `PackageManager` and `queryBroadcastReceivers()` to get the details of the receiver. You can then call `setComponentName()` on the `Intent` to make it explicit, before sending the broadcast:

```
private static void sendImplicitBroadcast(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
  PackageManager pm=ctxt.getPackageManager();
  List<ResolveInfo> matches=pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(i, 0);

  for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : matches) {
    Intent explicit=new Intent(i);
    ComponentName cn=
      new ComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
        resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);

    explicit.setComponent(cn);
    ctxt.sendBroadcast(explicit);
  }
}
```

See [my blog post on the implicit broadcast ban](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks, I succeed using intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
The problem with eventbus is that I need to register and unregister, but I still want to perform an action when receiving the brodcast even if the app has been in background (so event bus will not fit). I think I will have same problem with LocalBroadcastManager, need to check on this one

Comment: @Chol: "so event bus will not fit" -- it fits better than what you are doing. Even better would be to get rid of all of this and have more direct communications between the classes in these modules (e.g.,  RxJava).

Comment: But with event bus, event will not be receive as the activity will be unregsitered when app in background or killed, but I still need to make something once downloaded complete, even if the app is not there anymore. I will take a look on the RxJava if it can fits my needs, as you said if I can avoid a system brodcast it will be better

Comment: @Choi: "event will not be receive as the activity will be unregsitered when app in background or killed" -- activities are not "killed" in Android (they are destroyed, and processes are terminated, and that's it). Beyond that, there is no reason to be updating an activity that is not visible. It can pull in the latest status when it returns to the foreground. Stop wasting CPU time and battery life updating something that is not visible.

Comment: yeah understand that, once download is complete I'm setting the file as the new default ringtone. This part of code need to be executed even if app is not in foreground anymore. UI will be refresh only if displayed with eventBus

Comment: @Chol: Have the module that is doing the download set the file as the new default ringtone. Or, get rid of the modules, folding everything into a single module.

Comment: Maybe it is the best solution to make the download module setting the ringtone instead of throwing back to my module app. Thanks for all the information provided!

Comment: @Chol can u pls share how u resolved this issue ? facing same problem in Oreo tried Services but its also not working

Comment: @Erum don't remember, and I don't have the project anymore, but I think I stick with my first comment as it was working : "I succeed using intent.setClassName(packageName, className)"

Answer (score 0):

Please use [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)